# variable to change for finding OpenCV

Tags: linux, configuration, cmake, opencv3.0

I compiled an OpenCV.
I installed the .so files in `/usr/local/lib/opencv/` rather than `/usr/local/lib`, and the headers in `/usr/local/include/opencv` rather than `/usr/local/include`.

Now I am trying to compile Caffe library for another application and face some challenge for make it understand where are my OpenCV's files.

I do think a part of the solution is somewhere in the `/usr/local/share` files.

So I would like to know what I have to modify in :

```
OpenCVConfig.cmake,
OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
OpenCVModules.cmake
OpenCVModules-release.cmake
```

for make cmake understand where are my include / lib files ?

Comment: Script `OpenCVConfig.cmake`, like other `*Config.cmake` scripts, **is not intended for manual modification**. The same is true for other files you have listed. Content of these files is generated *automatically* while OpenCV is being configured and these files are installed with OpenCV. So, installed OpenCV files (including headers, libraries, etc.) **shouldn't be moved**. If you want these files installed at other location, you need to set pass appropriate `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable to CMake when *configure* OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I am going to recompile my OpenCV with the correct path.
Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identify by [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) when you compile opencv and want to install opencv it in an different path the default one (e.g. /usr/local/ on linux) it is better to modify the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in the `CMakeFile.txt` rather than move everything after installation.